# LinkedIn Talent Solutions Partnership

Tags: linkedin-api

I have applied for the LinkedIn Talent Solutions Partnership on october 12th 2018, and haven't got any feedback yet.

Does it seem normal to you ? Should I submit the form again or just wait for someone to get back to me ?

If anyone else applied for this program, how did it go for you ?

Thanks,

Wilhelm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming in any way.

Comment: I would agree with you if I hadn't been to told by a LinkdeIn representative to ask my question here. Applying to this program is supposed to allow me to use the LinkedIn API, so it could be related to programming, although I'll admit it's a bit far fetched ;)

Comment: Not sure why LinkedIn staff directed you here. Please see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) for why SO is not for customer service issues. If you had some code that utilized the LinkedIn API and were facing a problem with that, someone here may have been able to help, but that is not the case here. Perhaps, you could get in touch with LinkedIn again, show them the link shared above, and ask them why they would like you to post here?

Comment: I'm guessing the person that directed me there did so only because she couldn't help me directly, or maybe because there was a misunderstanding. Anyway, thanks for your answer and sorry for asking here, my mistake !

Comment: I doubt there is any misunderstanding per se, they have been doing this repeatedly and there's no evidence they care about SO's rules.

Comment: they indeed do this way too much. all sort of questions end up here because the linkedin support is too lazy to figure something like this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to wait 4-5 months aswell. so it seems pretty standard such a long waiting period.